How to understand "near interval" in Nelson's approach to nonstandard analysis?
I'm just starting to learn nonstandard analysis in hoping that I can apply this theory in statistics some day.
When reading Nelson's Radically Elementary Probability Theory, I couldn't understand what a near interval is. The first paragraph of Chapter 6 of the book reads

Let $T$ be a finite subset of $\mathbf{R}$. Throughout this book, we will use the
following notation: the first element of $T$ is $a$, the last is $b$, we let $T' =
T \setminus \lbrace b\rbrace$, for $t$ in $T'$  its successor is $t + dt$, and for any $\xi: T \rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ we write $d\xi(t) = \xi(t + dt)- \xi(t)$.
Whenever $\xi:T \rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ and we write $\xi(t)$, it is
understood that $t$ is in $T$. If $0\ll b - a \ll\infty$ and each $dt$ is infinitesimal,
we call $T$ a near interval.

My question is why the three conditions

$T$ being a finite set,
all $dt$ being infinitesimals, and
$0\ll b-a (\ll \infty)$

in the definition of near interval are not conflicting?
From the first 2 conditions, I thought that $b-a$ had to be a sum of finite number of infinitesimals. But then that implies $b-a$ is an infinitesimal and $0\ll b-a$ cannot hold.
Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

With this question in mind, I read Geyer's Radically Elementary Probability and Statistics, hoping to find some explanation. But its Section 4.4 reads

Following Nelson (1987, Chapter 9), we use the following notation. Let $T$
be a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$. For $t\in T$ such that $t\neq \max(T)$, we write $dt$ to mean the difference between $t$ and its successor in $T$, that is,
$$dt = \min\lbrace  u \in T : u > t \rbrace − t. \tag{4.6}$$
For $t = \max(T)$, we adopt the convention $dt = 0$. We call $dt$ the spacing of $T$
at $t$ and collectively refer to these $dt$ as the spacings of $T$.
If all the spacings $dt$ are infinitesimal and each $t \in T$ is limited, then we say
$T$ is a near interval. If all the spacings $dt$ are infinitesimal and $\min(T) \simeq -\infty$ and $\max(T) \simeq \infty$, then we say $T$ is a near line.

I got more confused and had more questions now:

Are these two definitions of "near interval" equivalent?
For Geyer's definition, if I choose $a=\min(T)=0$, then after adding a finite number of infinitesimals $dt$, $b=\max(T)$ is another infinitesimal. My intuition is that this definition only allows "intervals" of length $b-a$ approximately $0$. How could this resemble a general "interval" in the conventional sense?
Related to the above, if $a=\min(T)\simeq -\infty$, how could $b=\max(T)\simeq\infty$ with a finite number of $dt$ infinitesimal spacings in the definition of "near line"?


I guess my confusion seems centered around the finiteness of $T$ and all spacings being infinitesimal. But both authors seem to stress the importance of finiteness, e.g., probability is only defined on finite sample space and integral is only a finite sum. Can anyone please help explain and/or provide some intuition?

why do you think that a finite sum of infinitesimals has to be infinitesimal? That's definitely false.

@MatthewTowers Why is it definitely false? Did I misunderstand Corollary 3.8. of Geyer? That says:
If $x_1,\dots, x_n$ are infinitesimal real numbers and $n$ is a limited natural number, then $x_1 + \dots + x_n$ is infinitesimal.

that's correct, but it certainly doesn't say that a finite sum of infinitesimals is infinitesimal!

@MatthewTowers Sorry I'm still lost. Do you mean the number $|T|$ of elements in $T$ could be unlimited?  Theorem 2.1. of Geyer says "The numbers $1, 2,\dots, 10$ are limited."  Why couldn't I replace the $10$ by $|T|$?

Notice that did not say that "the numbers $1,2,\ldots$" are limited.

What you're missing is the following (perhaps counterintuitive) fact:
Take your favorite nonstandard natural number $\omega \in \mathbb{N}$. Then any set $T$ with $|T| = \omega$ is finite in Nelson's framework. In particular, the set $\{0,1,2,\dots,\omega - 1\}$ counts as a finite set. It is certainly not standard finite, nor limited, but it satisfies the definition of finite nonetheless.
With this fact in mind, let me answer your specific questions.
1. The three conditions in the definition of near interval are not conflicting.
You write:

I thought that $b-a$ had to be a sum of finite number of infinitesimals. But then that implies $b-a$ is an infinitesimal...

This is wrong. For example, the sum $$\sum_{n = 1}^{2\omega} \frac{21}{\omega}$$
consists of finitely many (exactly $2\omega$ many) infinitesimal terms, yet it has value $42$, which is far from infinitesimal.
The set $T = \left\{\frac{21}{\omega}, \frac{42}{\omega}, \frac{63}{\omega}, \dots,\frac{21(\omega-1)}{\omega}, \frac{21\omega}{\omega} \right\}$ in fact satisfies Nelson's definition of near-interval, since:

$|T| = \omega$, so in particular $T$ is finite;
All the $dt$ are equal to $\frac{21}{\omega}$ which is infinitesimal since the $\omega$ we chose in the beginning is a nonstandard natural;
$0 \ll b-a = \frac{21(\omega-1)}{\omega} < 21 \ll \infty$ holds.

II. Geyer's definition of near-interval is weaker than Nelson's. For example, the set $S = \left\{1 - \frac{1}{\omega}, 1\right\}$ is a near-interval in Geyer's sense since the spacing $\frac{1}{\omega}$ is infinitesimal and all elements are limited, but not in Nelson's sense since the difference $b - a = 1 - (1 - \frac{1}{\omega}) = \frac{1}{\omega}$ is infinitesimal, whereas Nelson's definition would also require $0 \ll b - a$.
However, any near-interval in Nelson's sense constitutes a near-interval in Geyer's sense. For example, the set $T$ above satisfies both definitions of near-interval.
About Geyer's definition, you write:

My intuition is that this definition only allows "intervals" of length b−a approximately 0.

This is again wrong, e.g. $T$ above has length close to 21, not approximately 0. Similarly, you can get a near-line that has unlimited length (exercise!).

Thanks a lot for the clear explanation!

There are two basic approaches to nonstandard analysis: the model-theoretic approach and the axiomatic approach.  In the model-theoretic approach, one extends $\mathbb R$ to a proper superfield ${}^\ast \mathbb R$, and finds infinitesimals there.  Here you get hypernaturals $H$ that are greater than all standard natural numbers.
In the axiomatic approach, one enriches the language of set theory by the addition of a one-place predicate "standard".  Then infinitesimals are found within $\mathbb R$ itself.  Integers can be standard or nonstandard; all of these are in $\mathbb N$.  To an $H$ as above corresponds a nonstandard integer $H\in\mathbb N$.  Thus $H$ is an integer and $\varepsilon =\frac1{H}$ is an infinitesimal.  Adding $\varepsilon$ to itself a finite (but nonstandard) number of times $H$, one gets the answer $1$.  In this way, an infinitesimal can be added to itself finitely many times to produce a non-infinitesimal answer.

Thanks for the clarification.  A subset $T$ with "finite but nonstandard" number of element is indeed what I missed.
